# No file creation with logging module in py2app mac application

Tags: python, macos, logging, permissions

I've got a python script that uses the logging module to create a log file. Using the following line:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='debug.lg',filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This works great as a script. After compiling with py2app the log file is no longer created.
If I change the above line to,

```
logging.basicConfig(format = '%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

and then force the console window open i get the expected logging printout. This tells me the logging module is working in my app.\

I anticipate this is some permission or virtual environment issue.

How do I make my log file be created (in the same directory that the app exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mac app appears to run in a virtual environment. I can force the app to run with a console window open and print `sys.argv[0]` I see that I'm four folders deep in my .app file. This is where the log file is being created. I'm unable to navigate here in finder. If i set the absolute path of the log file four folders up (the location of the .app file) the log file stays after execution.